# What is it called when you modify an older work to be more acceptable to modern audiences?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, general-vs-specific

Let's say you have a play that makes a bunch of short jokes. Someone goes to remove the short jokes so as to make it more acceptable to modern audiences. What is this called? (Generally, a word that means removing the parts of a work that are unacceptable by modern standards.)

I know that it would fall under censorship, but I need a word specific to this situation (censorship is too broad).

Comment: Well, "bowdlerizing" comes to mind.

Comment: @HotLicks Yep, that's a correct answer. Would you happen to know any words with better connotation (euphemisms)?

Comment: Modernizing, updating.

Comment: Try "edit", "censor", and "bowdlerize" in a thesaurus and see what you find.

Comment: @HotLicks You can make "bowdlerize" an answer if you like.

Comment: Sounds like the play's getting a makeover or face-lift; a "long-overdue makeover/face-lift" if you're talking about gratuitously offensive jokes, but if you'd been talking about the colorization of or replacing cigarettes with lollipops in classic films, I'd call it an "artistically offensive makeover/face-lift."

Comment: _"I know that it would fall under censorship"_ I'm not sure that it would, actually. At least, not in the general case.

Comment: "Expurgated" is another term with similar meaning that may be useful for searching. Consider also "dumbing down". Or "trampling merrily upon the blood, sweat and tears of artists far better than ourselves, causing them to spin in their graves at a rate whereby we can, with appropriately positioned turbines, power the entire theatre solely from the roiling of long-dead artists." 
Though that last may not be in most copies of Roget's.

Answer (score 6):

"[***Revamp***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revamp)" could be considered as it means:

> Give new and improved form, structure, or appearance to: ‘an attempt to revamp the museum’s image’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> To make (something) better or like new again: 'the company has revamped the design of its best-selling car'.

[[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revamp)]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest ***modernize*** as it conveys the idea clearly. Here is the definition from *OED* (emphasis mine):

> *trans.* To make modern, to bring up to date; to give a modern character or appearance to; to adapt to modern needs or habits; (sometimes) *spec.*
>
> **(a) to rewrite (an old text) in modern spelling or language; to change (obsolete spelling, words, or language) for modern equivalents;**
>
> (b) to remodel and refashion (an old building) in a modern style; to provide (a house, business, etc.) with modern conveniences or equipment.

Wikipedia has an article titled [*List of **modernized** adaptations of old works*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_modernized_adaptations_of_old_works).

Answer (score 3):

You may use ***[redact](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/redacted)***:

> - Literary & Literary Critical Terms):  *to put (a literary work, etc) into appropriate form for publication; edit.*

also  ***[adapt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adapt):***

> - (tr) to fit, change, or modify to suit a new or different purpose:
>
>   - *to adapt a play for use in schools.*

The Free Dictionary

List of modernised ***[adaptations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_modernized_adaptations_of_old_works)*** of old works. (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **revise**. It's a bit more general as it covers insertions as well as deletions, but could work too:

> To prepare a **newly edited version of (a text)**.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=revise))

For example, a late 19th-century translation of the Bible is called [The Revised Version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revised_Version) (or English Revised Version).